# google.guava.CountingInputStream does not give correct offset while iterating over the file line by line

Tags: java, collections, guava, apache-commons-io

I am trying to get the line start offset with reading a file from start to end. My purpose is to build an index [Line_number --> start_Offset in file]. Used following Guava library, Sample code and library used are as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>28.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
try {
    ByteSource byteSource = Files.asByteSource(new File(filePath));
    CountingInputStream cStream = new CountingInputStream(byteSource.openStream());
    Iterator<String> lines = byteSource.asCharSource(defaultCharset()).lines().iterator();
    //lines.forEachRemaining((line) -> System.out.println(input.getCount()));
    while (lines.hasNext()) {
        //String line = lines.next();
        //System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("OFFSET:" + cStream.getCount());
    }   
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
OFFSET:0
OFFSET:0
OFFSET:0
OFFSET:0
.
.
.
```

Though it prints the content of the line (If I uncomment the code - `System.out.println(line)`), all the lines OFFSET is 0. Why the correct offset (`line_start`) is not returned and what is missing in above code-snippet? Do I need to manually skip the line `cStream.skip(line.length());` every time and then do `cStream.getCount()`? Is there any other recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to post some sample of the file so people can test.

Comment: You are bypassing `byteSource` by reading `lines` directly from the `byteSource`, so the decorator fails to increment the byte count.

Comment: @Ben Manes, It would be really helpful if you elaborate what do you mean by "bypassing byteSource by reading lines directly from the byteSouce". Can you pls post the correct code. File path is any text-file containing multiple lines having ASCII chars.

Comment: `lines = byteSource...` does not use `cStream`, which itself calls `byteSource.openStream()`. You are actually reading from the file twice, once via `asCharSource` and again by `cStream`. Since you never consume `cStream` it has zero bytes read. Please review your code line-by-line and you'll see that `cStream` is unused.

Comment: The correct code would be to use `BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cStream, UTF_8)).lines() `

Comment: Please look into `BufferedReader`. By providing it the `cStream` source it can provide the lines. The data will be read from `cStream` which allows you to then query for the byte count. You should not need further explanation, just a time to experiment with that api.

Comment: @Ben Manes, I have incorporated your suggestion in my code (experiment), but getting offset= last char offset in file for all lines instead of their respective line start offset. Kindly guide, what is missing here.

Comment: ByteSource byteSource = Files.asByteSource(new File(filePath));
            CountingInputStream cStream = new CountingInputStream(byteSource.openStream());
            Stream<String> stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cStream, US_ASCII)).lines();
            Iterator<String> lineIterator = stream.iterator();
            while (lineIterator.hasNext()) {
                String line = lineIterator.next();
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println(cStream.getCount());
            }

Comment: Sorry, this is probably because the BufferedReader will consume N bytes extra, to improve performance. The `CharSource#lines()` will have the same problem. The simplest is to use a buffer size of `1` and subtract that from the count but risk off-by-one errors. Otherwise you will have to implement line-by-line reading of the input stream yourself, e.g. checking the line ending character for termination. The utilities don't offer exactly what you want out of the box.

Comment: @Ben Manes, Thanks a lot for clarification and your prompt answer.

Comment: @Ben Manes,  I tried earlier approach as you suggested (line by line reading and checking line ending char), but the issue here is taking too much time on large file as length of each line is variable (not known prior) and have to read single char at a time... Kindly share your input or reference if any that can help here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is the problem with char-by-char, and why buffering is used to reduce system call overhead. You now have to implement buffering and the count calculation yourself, so that you can read N bytes ahead and output the right offset values.

Comment: You could try using a buffered RandomAccessFile, see this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20070315095923/https://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip26.html) which offers a guided walkthrough of an implementation. Then use `readLine` and `getFilePointer`.

Comment: And [here](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/23d21a8ba7b05e0fd7fe34eb06fadf24d975fa82/fontbox/src/main/java/org/apache/fontbox/ttf/BufferedRandomAccessFile.java) is an Apache impl of that class. Note that you have to add back in `getNextLine` and double check, so it may be easier to write it from scratch.